# Is it a good idea to drive 24VAC solenoid valves with triacs?

Tags: ac, relay, coil, triac, solenoid-valve

I want to build irrigation system for my garden. Most solenoid valves for that purpose work at 24VAC.

I'm wondering if I could use triacs to drive them. They are cheap and small (in comparison with relays) but I have some concerns about overcurrent and short-circuit conditions (like coil interturn short circuits, cables damaged by rodents etc.) and voltage drop (relatively high at 24VAC).

I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

**How this is done in commercial irrigation systems?** <- edit: is this question opinion based?

Relays, triacs or maybe something else?

Comment: Not opinion based imo.

Comment: I thought most solenoid valves use 12V or 24V DC, and for either DC or AC no one is using traics. Can you let us know the links to the applications you mentioned?

Comment: The residential irrigation controllers I've had have used TRIACs to drive the valves and AC excitation.

Comment: I echo what Kevin says. A 16A triac is cheap and you’re probably not likely to have  anywhere near 16A available from the supply, so it should be pretty robust. You can use polyfuses to limit the current. Relays can be sourced cheaply as well but make sure you put a varistor across the solenoid as relays don’t switch at zero crossing.

Comment: @tlfong01 Take a look at Rain Bird GB-R Sprinkler Valves for example. In systems like this everything is powered from 24V transformer for safety

Comment: @KevinWhite I think that could be an answer.

Comment: @Kamil: Thank you for your reference. The AC vs DC power issue seems a bit complicated. I need to google harder to confirm (1) if AC24V power is better than DC12V, and in which situations (eg, AC solenoid valve takes smaller current, therefore less voltage drop (higher efficiency) for remote/distance/long wiring applications.) (2) Is it appropriate to use Triac or Solid State Relay (SSR). (3) Ref: (a) ***Understanding 24VAC Sprinkler Valves*** - ray, 2014aug22: https://rayshobby.net/wordpress/understanding-24vac-sprinkler-valves/, (b) SSR: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_relay.

Comment: @tlfong01 In general AC solenoids are more efficient in terms of energy and/or amount of copper used to manufacture them.

Comment: @Kamil: I am googling further to update my knowledge in AC solenoids. (3) AC Vs. DC Solenoids & How They Work - Michelle Kerns  2018mar14:
https://sciencing.com/dc-solenoids-how-they-work-5008123.html.

(4) Using AC coils on DC power - Roger Hoestenbach, 1995jul01:
https://www.ecmweb.com/content/article/20889628/using-ac-coils-on-dc-power.

Comment: @Kamil. You questions is in 2 independent parts: (3) Whether to use an AC or a DC power solenoid value, (4) Whether to use an electromagnetic or a SSR (Solid State Relay). You might like to skim my old posts to see how I learn to use a SSR: (5) Solid State Relay DIY Notes (MCP23017 Driving GM3B202P SSR (Sold State Relay) - Forums.rpi.com
https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=1421596&hilit=ky019+tlfong01#p1421582

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most modern irrigation controllers use triacs to control the solenoids.  However, relays work also well and have the possible advantage of galvanic isolation between the control and load sides of the circuit.

We use Aromat (NAIS / Panasonic) JS1 relays by the tens of thousands.  We find they are more cost effective than the (beefy) triacs that our loads would require.  Although the coils are DC, the contacts handle AC or DC with no problems.

If you do decide to use triacs, over-size them to accommodate the occasional short circuit that inevitably happens.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **relays** or you can use **MOSFETs** or **FETs** or **BJTs** which are inexpensive too and have good current handling capacity (assuming you will be using any microcontroller for triggering the MOSFET at desired timings or needs).

And don't forget the protection components like a freewheeling diode for back-EMF control and a capacitor for power supply.